# Labelling centred text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, labels

I have two lines of text which I would like centred in my document. I have used

```
\begin{center}
\end{center}
```

To do this, but would like to label it with a symbol such as an ace of spades just like we label an equation with numbers.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried putting the text in an equation environment and using `\text{}` but this didn't work out too well since the text is more than one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `array` or, as Barbara Beeton seggested, a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    You could use an \texttt{array}, see \ref{mytext}:
    \[
    \begin{array}{M{.4\textwidth}}% put here the length you like
        Some text which is more than one line.
    \end{array}\label{mytext}\tag{$\spadesuit$}
    \]
    As Barbara Beeton suggested in her comment, also 
    a \texttt{minipage} works, see \ref{barbara}.
    \[
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}% put here the length you like
        \centering 
        Some text which is more than one line.
    \end{minipage}\label{barbara}\tag{$\clubsuit$}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thank you very much.

Comment: @ABitTooCurious You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!

Comment: rather than using an `array`, a `minipage` should also work.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Minipage alternative added, thank you!